# Apache Spark to S3 upload performance Issue

Tags: amazon-s3, hdfs, apache-spark, emr

I'm seeing a major performance issue when Apache Spark uploads its results to S3. As per my understanding it goes these steps...

1. Output of final stage is written to `_temp/` table in HDFS and the same is moved into `"_temporary"` folder inside the specific `S3` folder.
2. Once the whole process is done - Apache spark completes the `saveAsTextFile` stage and then files inside `"_temporary"` folder in `S3` are moved into the main folder. This is actually taking a long time [ approximately 1 min per file (average size : 600 MB BZ2) ]. This part is not getting logged in the usual `stderr` log.

I'm using Apache `Spark 1.0.1` with `Hadoop 2.2` on AWS EMR.

Has anyone encountered this issue ?

**Update 1**

How can I increase the number of threads that does this move process ?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed with SPARK-3595 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3595).  Which was incorporated in builds 1.1.0.e and later (see https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/spark).

Answer (score 0):

I use below functions . it uploads file to s3. it uploads around  60 gb , gz files in 4-6 mins.

```
        ctx.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator",
                ",");
        counts.saveAsHadoopFile(s3outputpath, Text.class, Text.class,
                TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Make sure that you create more output files . more number of smaller files will make upload faster.

API details
saveAsHadoopFile[F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat[_, *]](path: String, **keyClass**: Class[*], **valueClass**: Class[*], **outputFormatClass**: Class[F], codec: Class[* <: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec]): Unit
Output the RDD to any Hadoop-supported file system, compressing with the supplied codec.

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer ? It does not work form...using "Text.class" throws error...

Comment: you can use function as  saveAsHadoopFile[F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat[_, _]](path: String, keyClass: Class[_], valueClass: Class[_], outputFormatClass: Class[F], codec: Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec]): Unit
Output the RDD to any Hadoop-supported file system, compressing with the supplied codec. Put class for your key and value